# Unable to reset the data form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to reset the data in jQuery. I am trying to save the data using jQuery its happening. But when I click on remove glyph-icon, data is not reset in the form. I tried a code but it is not working. When I click on remove icon also the data is being saved. I am stuck with place the reset code. Used glyphicons to save and reset the data. I do not wish do abort in ajax.

```js
//Banking details form validation
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editBankDetailBtn').click(function() {
    if ($('.editBankDetail').is('[readonly]')) { //checks if it is already on readonly mode
      $('.editBankDetail').prop('readonly', false); //turns the readonly off

      $('.editBankDetailBtn').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">&nbsp;</span>' + '<span id="reset-form" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">&nbsp;</span>');
      //  $('.glyphicon-remove')[0].reset();

    } else { //else we do other things

      var patt = /^([0-9]{11})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})$/;
      var reg = /^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6,7}$/;
      patt.test('acdbdfdsfsf22-333-666666'); // true

      var bname_1 = document.getElementById('bankName').value;

      if (bname_1 == "") {

        document.getElementById('bankName').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('bankName').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
      }

      var aaccount_number = document.getElementById('accountNumber');
      if (!patt.test(aaccount_number.value)) {

        document.getElementById('accountNumber').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('accountNumber').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
      }

      var bifsc = document.getElementById('ifscCode').value;

      if (!reg.test(ifscCode.value)) {

        document.getElementById('ifscCode').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('ifscCode').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
      }

      var bank_address = document.getElementById('branchAddress').value;

      if (bank_address == "") {

        document.getElementById('branchAddress').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('branchAddress').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
      }

      $('.editBankDetail').prop('readonly', true);
      $('.editBankDetailBtn').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');

    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.glyphicon-remove').on('click', function() {
        $("#reset-form").trigger("reset");
      });

    });

  });
});

function saveBankDetail() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update-bankdetail.html',
    type: "post",
    data: {
      bankName: $('#bankName').val(),
      branchAddress: $('#branchAddress').val(),
      accountNumber: $('#accountNumber').val(),
      ifscCode: $('#ifscCode').val(),

    }

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't need to wait for document ready again when doing the reset, you're already waiting for that at a higher level. The "reset-form" id is set on a span, you need to set it on a form in order for the reset event to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `$(document).ready(...)` within `$(document).ready(...)`. Note that the event is only fired once, which means that the inner one is never fired. You have also nested the click events (not recommended).

Your code should be looking something like:

```
$(document)
        .ready(
            function() {
                $('.editBankDetailBtn').click(function() {
                       ...
                };

                $('.glyphicon-remove').on('click', function() {
                       $("#reset-form").trigger("reset");
                });
...
```